# Merge [handlebars.js] and [handlebars]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I just searched on [handlebars](/questions/tagged/handlebars). Got quite a few questions. Then I realized there is also a [handlebars.js](/questions/tagged/handlebars.js) tag, with many more questions.

Can I suggest they all be merged into one or the other?

Comment: Someone already suggested `handlebars` as a  [synonym of `handlebars.js`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/handlebars.js/synonyms).

Comment: There's also [tag:mustache] and [tag:mustache.js]. [tag:ember] and [tag:underscore] are two tags already synonimized to their .js counterparts.

Comment: I cam here to ask this as well, Darren. As we lack the reputation to vote on this tag synonym, is there anything else we can do to speed this along?